# Are Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2012 solutions"compatible"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, backwards-compatibility, assemblyinfo

I edited my project (which was written in school using Visual Studio 2008) at home using Visual Studio 2010 Express. When I got back to school, I couldn't open my solution anymore as Visual Studio 2008 told me that the file was created with a newer version of Visual Studio. I asked my professor for help and he edited something in the assembly information of the solution and voila, I could open, run, edit it again as nothing ever happened.

However, I forgot what he did with the assembly information. Does anyone here know what he could have done? or is this approach not advisable?

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the `.sln` file there would be a line:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
```

If you change the version to `10.00`, it would correspond to Visual Studio 2008. Use any text editor for this.

The file format has not changed in between these versions (nor has it for Visual Studio 2012).

Comment: but why does everybody keep saying that these versions are not backwards compatbible when they (even though only through this workaround) actually are?

Comment: Who is everybody that says that?

Comment: people on forums and classmates. they were just bull********* me werent they?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the .sln file in Notepad and find the version number (11.0) on the first or second line. Change it to 10.0, save the file, and you should be good to go.

Comment: does this work in every vs-version that is using the same or an older framework version?

Comment: @LeonidasFett VS2008 cannot target .Net 4.0, so if your VS2010 solution code utilises any classes and types specific to the 4.0 framework then it won't build in VS2008, AFAIK. See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/09a309a0-a8fc-407d-9fb5-7e1c1a26d397